# How to pass parameter from simple html page to another angular page using form post method?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

this is my simple test.html file and i wanted to pass employeeId to localhost:4200/homePage. When i use get method then it working fine but with post getting error Cannot Post

```
<form action="localhost:4200/homePage" name="goToAngular" method="post">
<input type="text" name="employeeID" value="" id="apiUrl" id="employeeID"/>
<input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

On the homePage-component.ts file i am using this code--

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => 
this.empID = params['employeeID'];
}
```

Comment: you cant use POST to send params, its not working like this on Angular.
you have other ways to do it. you can use Services/ngrx and so many other ways(even with cookie\session what ever)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to send data from **page1** `component` to **page2** `component` and `route` to that component in Angular on submit of the form.

You should make use of `(ngSubmit)` directive available by `Angular`

Try making following changes :

**page1.component.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()">
<input type="text" name="employeeID" value="" id="apiUrl" id="employeeID" [(ngModel)]="empId" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**page1.component.ts**

```
empId = "";

constructor(private router : Router) {} 

formSubmit(){
  this.router.navigate(['/home',{queryParameter : {employeeId : this.empId}}])
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div>{{employeeId}}</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
employeeId : String

constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) {} 

ngOnInit(){
 this.route.queryParamters.subscribe(data=>{
   this.employeeId = data['employeeId']
 })
}
```

You will also need to define routes in your application.
Check out official [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Is it mandatory to use angular for both end ? I mean 1st end i have a html file in which i can angular js but at other end i am using angular 6. so i cann't have test.component.ts file at 1st end